# how can i show users that they are logged in at html page?

Tags: php, html, session

I created my website and there are many pages with .html and .php.
In the case of .php pages, I could show messages to users such as 'welcome, {$username}!'
However in html pages I can't!

In my case, should I change every .html page to .php pages to show message like above?
I tried that, but then my apache server go too slow, so I need another solution if exists.

Can I make .html pages partially behave like php or other things?

Comment: Either figure out why your server becomes so slow and fix that; or use Javascript to fetch the login status and display it in HTML.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show dynamic content you either have to use php code, or write some javascript to replace the content (which will eventually need to use php aswell)

You should save your files as a php file

Answer (score 0):

> In my case, should I change every .html page to .php pages to show message like above?

Yes.

> Can I make .html pages partially behave like php or other things?

You can tell Apache to process all HTML documents as PHP, but that will give you the same performance issues that you have having when you rename them, so it won't solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Save the file as php then run a cache...
add this to the top of the page

```
$url = $_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"];
$break = Explode('/', $url);
$file = $break[count($break) - 1];
$cachefile = 'my-cache/cached-'.substr_replace($file ,"",-4).'.html';
$cachetime = 60; //Time

if (file_exists($cachefile) && time() - $cachetime < filemtime($cachefile)) {
    echo "<!-- Cached copy, generated ".date('H:i', filemtime($cachefile))." -->\n";
    readfile($cachefile);
    exit;
}

ob_start();
```

Then add this to the bottom of the page

```
$cached = fopen($cachefile, 'w');
fwrite($cached, ob_get_contents());
fclose($cached);
ob_end_flush();
```